# Изменить число в строке javascript

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте, такая задача: нужно написать функцию, которая будет выводить измененную строку, а именно если мы получаем строку 'foo' -> 'foo1', 'foo000' -> 'foo001', 'foo001' -> 'foo002', 'foo99' -> 'foo100', 'foo099' -> 'foo100'

Написал такую функцию, но потом понял, что эта функция меняет только последнюю цифру в строке. И теперь не могу понять как прибавлять единицу к числам 001, 099 и т.д. , чтобы когда нужно нули оставались(077 -> 078), а когда не нужны то уходили(099 -> 100)

```js
function incrementString (strng) {
  var numbOfString = strng.match(/[0-9]/ig);
  var numbArray = [];

  if (/[0-9]/i.test(strng)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numbOfString.length; i++) {
      numbArray.push(parseInt(numbOfString[i]));
    }

    var lastAddValue = numbArray[numbArray.length - 1] + 1;

    var editedStrng = strng.slice(0, -1);
    editedStrng = editedStrng + lastAddValue;
    return editedStrng;
  } 
  return strng + '1';
}
```

**UPD: цифры могут быть только в конце строки. Сколько цифр в строке будет неизвестно, строка может быть и такой foo00000001**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Чтобы было максимально легко разобраться, я постарался лишь модифицировать ваш пример:

```js
function incrementString(strng, base, decrease) {
  var base = base || 3;

  var numbOfString = strng.match(/[0-9]/ig);
  var numbArray = '';

  if (/[0-9]/i.test(strng)) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numbOfString.length; i++) {
      numbArray += numbOfString[i];
    }

    numbArray = parseInt(numbArray);

    var lastAddValue = numbArray + (decrease? -1 : 1);
    return strng.replace(/\d/g, '') + pad(lastAddValue, base);
  }
  return strng + pad(1, base);
}

function pad(num, size) {
  var s = num + "";
  while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
  return s;
}

console.log(incrementString('foo', 1));
console.log(incrementString('foo000'));
console.log(incrementString('foo001'));
console.log(incrementString('foo077'));
console.log(incrementString('foo089', 2));
console.log(incrementString('foo099'));
console.log(incrementString('foof099', 3, true));
console.log(incrementString('foof100', 3, true));
console.log(incrementString('foof60', 3, true));
```

Добавилось 2 параметра:

- основание (*base*), указывающее, сколько цифр должно быть в итоговой строке. Если не передан, то будет равняться 3.
- необязательный флаг *decrease*, указывающий, что необходимо уменьшение счетчика, а не увеличение

Хочу отметить, что тут имеется весьма забавный... ммм "артефакт".

Так как регулярное выражение тут требует доработки, переданная строка, например такая, тоже отработает и выведет нужный результат:

```
console.log(incrementString('1f2o3o', 3));
```

> foo124

Я специально назвал это "артефактом", так как кто-то может расценить это как фичу, а кто-то как баг =)

**UPD после комментариев**

```js
function incrementString(strng, decrease) {

  var numbOfString = strng.match(/[0-9]/ig);
  var number;
  
  if (numbOfString) {
    number = +numbOfString.join('');

    var lastAddValue = number + (decrease? -1 : 1);
    return strng.replace(/\d/g, '') + pad(lastAddValue, numbOfString.length);
  }
  return strng + pad(1, 1);
}

function pad(num, size) {
  var s = num + "";
  while (s.length < size) s = "0" + s;
  return s;
}

console.log(incrementString('foo', 1));
console.log(incrementString('foo000'));
console.log(incrementString('foo001'));
console.log(incrementString('foo077'));
console.log(incrementString('foo089'));
console.log(incrementString('foo099'));
console.log(incrementString('foof099', true));
console.log(incrementString('foof100', true));
console.log(incrementString('foof60', true));

console.log(incrementString('foo00000001'));
console.log(incrementString('foo0009999'));
console.log(incrementString('foo999999'));
```

Comment: Блин, я совсем забыл указать, что числа могут быть только в конце строки. Но вот проблема, суть функции, что неизвестно сколько чисел будет в строке. Извиняюсь за неверное описание=/

Comment: не чисел, а цифр

Comment: @nazarukroman а, ну так это ок, сейчас обновлю ответ

Comment: @Mr.Brightside, блин, круто, спасибо, то что нужно! К сожалению, сам не пришел к этому... :(

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд вы слишком усложнили себе задачу. Ваше решение больше похоже на учебное упражнение. Тело функции может быть в одну строку:

```
function incrementString(str) {
  return str.replace(/\d*$/, s => ('' + (+s + 1)).padStart(s.length, '0'));
}
```

```js
function incrementString(str) {
  return str.replace(/\d*$/, //находим все цифры в конце строки и заменяем
    s => (
      '' + (+s + 1) //на найденные цифры, преобразовыванные в число + 1
    ).padStart(s.length, '0') //дополненные нулями
  );
}

console.log(incrementString('foo'));
console.log(incrementString('foo000'));
console.log(incrementString('foo001'));
console.log(incrementString('foo077'));
console.log(incrementString('foo089'));
console.log(incrementString('foo099'));
console.log(incrementString('foof099'));
console.log(incrementString('foof100'));
console.log(incrementString('foof999'));
```

Comment: да, это учебное задание. Ваш пример компактнее намного и лучше. Просто не мог понять как мне из строки взять цифры(сейчас вижу *$). Плюс не знаком с таким элементом (=>) и не знаком с методом padStart.

Comment: @nazarukroman См. [стрелочные функции](https://learn.javascript.ru/es-function#%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7). [`padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) пока поддерживается не везде. Трюк в соседнем ответе сработает даже в IE6

Comment: спасибо за ссылки!

Answer (score 0):

вариант ...

```js
function incrementString(d) {
  return d.replace(/(0*)(\d*$)/, function(b, a, c) {
    return (a + ++c).slice(a ? -b.length : 0);
  });
}

console.log(incrementString('foo'));
console.log(incrementString('foo000'));
console.log(incrementString('foo001'));
console.log(incrementString('foo9'));
console.log(incrementString('foo099'));
console.log(incrementString('foo999'));
```